# Decimal floating point to fixed point conversion

Tags: c, matlab, decimal, fixed-point

I'm attempting to scale the value `1e-4` in fixed point format, but I'm having difficulties getting accurate results.
I would be very grateful for any assistance. .

Matlab :

`fprintf('%10.16f|%10d|\n',fi(1e-4,0,32),storedInteger(fi(1e-4,0,32)))`

`0.0001000000000033 | 3518437209|`

and

I'm doing this in C fixed point notation.

`uint32_t eps = 3518437209;`

`eps = (uint32_t)(eps / ((uint64_t)1 << 45));`

In contrast to my anticipation of

`0.0001000000000033`

the value of eps is

`0`

Thank you!!

Comment: What do you expect to get when dividing a `uint32_t` by a `uint64_t` that is greater than `UINT32_MAX`? That is always less than `1`, i.e. the `0` you are getting. I suggest casting `(double)eps` before the division.

Comment: Even if I can eliminate typecast, your suggestion for double puzzles me.
I believe double is not permitted for fixed point.

Comment: IDK you only posted that line of code, and my comment states why it can never work. Without any `double` in sight, how do you expect the result to be the required `0.0001000000000033` unless you write a converter manually?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want to use fixed point values you normally **interpret** an integer value as a fixed point value. There is no standard fixed point arithmetics in C, it all depends on the implementation. If you want to *print* the value you can convert it to `double` and divide it by the required value or you can do some bit shifting, masking and scaling and print the integer and fractional parts separately.

Comment: I added typecast to ensure that there is no data loss, but it cannot add value because eps is already 32 bit size, despite being divided by a 64 bit.

(uint32_t)3518437209/((uint64_t)1 << 45);
To represent 3518437209, 31.7123 bits are required.

Comment: If you can't use `double` then the output shown must be a string. When using fixed point I have typically used a power-of-10 scaling factor. Then I can do a normal integer-to-string conversion and insert a decimal point in the right place.

Comment: The question does not make sense as posted. First, the title asks for converting floating-point to fixed-point. But the division by `(uint64_t) 1 << 45` would be part of converting fixed-point to floating-point. Second, it would indicate a fixed-point format with 45 bits after the decimal point. But `eps` is `uint32_t`, which has only 32 bits. You could have a fixed-point format with such scaling, but it would be very unusual.

Comment: I was wondering about the power-of-2 shift too. The question states the scale factor is `1e-4`

Comment: In any case, if `eps` is the integer encoding of a fixed point format with scaling 2^45, a way to convert it from the fixed-point encoding to a floating-point value is to divide by 2^45, as with `eps * 0x1p-45`. Conversely, if `x` is a floating-point value, a way to convert it to a fixed-point encoding with scaling 2^45 is to multiply by 2^45 and round to an integer, as with `round(x * 0x1p45)`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I think the scale factor is 2^45 and the sample value they are trying to convert is .0001.

Comment: @Eric that would explain the low-end digits in `0.0001000000000033`, from computation error.

Comment: @ Weather Vane
I believe you misunderstood what a fixed point was.
Read Matlab Conversion first, then watch how I get to a fixed point value.


3518437209 / 2^45 = 1.0000e-04

Comment: As stated, you cannot do integer division of a 32-bit number by 2^45 and get a fractional result.

Comment: According to https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/create-fixed-point-data.html, the code `fi(1e-4,0,32)` creates an unsigned fixed point number with the value `1.0e-4` and 32 bits total. If I undestand correct, Matlab somehow chooses the size of the fractional part or the scaling automatically. I don't know how to get the scaling factor.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some background information about what you want to achieve and/or what's your use case for fixed point data. Fixed point or fractional arithmetics are often used in embedded systems that use a CPU without a floating point unit or with a slow FPU.

Comment: @Bodo According to https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/embedded.fi.html, the default fraction precision is 15 bits.  So I would expect `fi(1e-4,0,32)` to yield 0.0001 × 32768 = 3.  I don't know where 3518437209 came from.

Comment: @SteveSummit, 3518437209 is value stored in fixed point for 32 bit word size.

real world value=stored integer×2 ^−fraction length
fprintf('%10.16f\n',3518437209 * 1/2^45)
0.0001000000000033
                       =

Comment: @Coder How do you get the fraction length in Matlab?

Comment: @SteveSummit The documentation has room for interpretation. One example from https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/embedded.fi.html is also in the documentation I found: `a = fi(pi,1,8)` ... WordLength: 8 FractionLength: 5. And https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/create-fixed-point-data.html states: *Default Fixed-Point Attributes ... Note that when the FractionLength property is not specified, it is set automatically to "best precision" for the given word length, keeping the most-significant bits of the value.* The default 15 seems to apply only to `a=fi` (without arguments)

Comment: @Bodo Right.  I just found the same thing.  So `fi(1e-4,0,32)` and `fi(1e4,0,32)` will choose *different scale factors*.  To me that sounds like an expensive simulation of floating point, but what do I know?

Comment: Try this 

clc
RealWorld8 =  storedInteger(fi(1e-4,0,8,21)); 
RealWorld16 = storedInteger(fi(1e-4,0,16,29));
RealWorld32 = storedInteger(fi(1e-4,0,32,45));
fprintf('%15s|%15s|%15s|\n---------------+---------------+---------------+\n','RealWorld8','RealWorld16','RealWorld32');
fprintf('%15d|%15d|%15d|\n',RealWorld8,RealWorld16, RealWorld32);



     RealWorld8|    RealWorld16|    RealWorld32|
---------------+---------------+---------------+
            210|          53687|     3518437209|

Comment: @SteveSummit,

I would be very grateful if you could help me with the indentation keys.
You can easily comprehend how it operates.

Comment: @Coder You can [edit] your question, copy&paste a code block to the question and insert a line with 3 backticks or 3 tilde characters (`~~~`) as a separate line before and after the code block. Alternatively you can indent it by 4 spaces using the `{}` tool of the editor field. With 4 arguments, e.g. in `fi(1e-4,0,8,21)`, you explicitly specify both word length and fraction length. I was curious how to get the automatically calculated fraction length when you did not explicitly specify it, e.g. in `fi(1e-4,0,32)`.

Comment: quite straightforward:
A correct fraction length would be Number = log2(Number).

Format : Signedness, WordLength, FractionLength
For  decimal / Fractional values 
0.0001 * 2^+1
0.0001 * 2^+12
0.0001 * 2^+13
0.0001 * 2^+14 , You have 1 as integer , so 15 bits as fractional , and sign is + ve means , WL = IL + FL otherwise its WL = IL - FL
I hope its clear for you

Comment: I am not getting the indentation correct
{clc
 RealWorld8 =  storedInteger(fi(1e-4,0,8,21)); 
 RealWorld16 = storedInteger(fi(1e-4,0,16,29));
 RealWorld32 = storedInteger(fi(1e-4,0,32,45));
 fprintf('%15s|%15s|%15s|\n---------------+---------------+---------------+\n','RealWorld8','RealWorld16','RealWorld32');
 fprintf('%15d|%15d|%15d|\n',RealWorld8,RealWorld16, RealWorld32);}

Comment: @Coder Are you using a shift of 45 bits because you want to, or because that's what Matlab picked for that one value 1e-4?  I'm no expert on fixed-point arithmetic, but I would say that 45 bits is a *very* unusual shift value.  With 32 bits, you're not going to be able to represent numbers bigger than about 1.22e-4.  Also it's not going to be easy to work with a shift that big, at all, especially if you're not allowed to use true floating-point arithmetic (i.e. type `double`), or 64-bit arithmetic.

Comment: @Coder Take this with a grain of salt, because as I said, I'm no fixed-point expert, but if it was me, and unless I had some crazy big or crazy tiny numbers to work with, I think I'd go with something more like the equivalent of `fi(1e-4,0,32,16)` or maybe `fi(1e-4,0,32,20)`.  What kinds of numbers *are* you planning to work with, other than 1e-4?

Comment: @SteveSummit I have to use it in my calculations because of some necessity.
And I can't escape it

Take the floating point value of 0.005 as an illustration.
What is the integer and fractional length if asked to represent anything in fixed point for 8 bits?

Fractional length is always greater than integer length in these circumstances.
Because ,

{    log2(0.0050)

ans =

   -7.6439    }

Comment: DataTypeMode for 0.0050 is 
"             WordLength: 8
        FractionLength: 15  "

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this in C — which I concede may not meet your requirements — is with something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    double val = 1e-4;
    uint32_t ival = val * 35184372088832. + 0.5;
    printf("%u\n", ival);
}
```

That magic scaling factor `35184372088832.` is simply 2<sup>45</sup>, and I'm adding `0.5` so that it rounds to the nearest fixed-point value.  This is an obvious way to do it, and it works fine for "ordinary" values, but it probably doesn't work so well for extreme values, and I'm not even sure it has guaranteed behavior for input values greater than about 1.22e-4.

To convert the fixed-point value back to floating-point so you can print it out, just do the reverse:

```
double val2 = ival / 35184372088832.;
printf("%.16f\n", val2);
```

On my machine, this prints `0.0001000000000033`.

If you want to do any of this *without* using values or arithmetic involving type `double`, it can be done, but it's going to be a lot harder.

Comment: You analysis make sense ,

{   fprintf( '%10.10f|%10.10f|%10u|\n' , 3518437209 / 2 ^ 45,35184372088832 / 2^45, 2 ^ 45)
0.0001000000|1.0000000000|35184372088832|  }

Comment: But the problem is one need 45 bits to represent !! log2(35184372088832) = 45. Still need some more work

Comment: @Coder That's not quite true.  You can use 32 bits with a 45-bit shift, **but** you'll only be able to represent numbers between 0.0 and 1.22e-4.  Even if you use 45 bits with a 45-bit shift, you'll only be able to represent numbers in the range of 0.0 to 1.0.  To represent numbers greater than 1, you'd need *more* than 45 bits.  That's why I said I thought 45 was an unusual shift value.

Comment: You can accomplish it; I revised the computation, and I believe it will be successful for the majority of floating-to-fixed conversions.


#define Q_CONVERT_FXP(x, y) ((float)(x) / ((int64_t)1 << (y)))
double y = Q_CONVERT_FXP(3518437209, 45);
y = 9.9999997473787516e-05;
>> fprintf('%10.10f\n', y );
0.0001000000
>> fprintf('%10.16f\n', y);
0.0000999999974738

Although I hope it is apparent, I always appreciate improvement.

Comment: @Coder You will get substantially more accurate results if you use `(double)(x)` rather than `(float)(x)`.  Also it's probably safer to use `(uint64_t)1 << (y)`, or more simply, `1ull << (y)`.

Comment: I like your idea and would rather use 1ULL, but I also believe double allocates more bits than necessary. If more accuracy is required, I can typecast float to double.

I hope the challenging topic appealed to you as it did to me.
I greatly appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Believe what you wish, but: that cast to `double` does not "allocate more memory" — what it in fact does is cause the calculation to be carried out using double rather than single precision, which will give you twice the precision, require no more memory, and under many circumstances won't even take any longer.

Comment: Also, whether you realize it or not, it's implicit in your question that you care a great deal about precision.  A 45-bit shift gives you a precision of 2e-14.  That's pretty precise!  To me, at least, using a 45-bit shift, but then throwing half of your precision away by using type `float` in an intermediate result, is crazy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245928/discussion-between-coder-and-steve-summit).